# How to set wireless key with nmcli interactively and securely without entering it in the command

Tags: networking, command-line, security, wifi, nmcli

I can set my wifi key of the connection `my_connection` to `my_password` by running

```
nmcli con modify my_connection wifi-sec.psk my_password
```

How can I have a secured interactive password reading from `nmcli`, i.e with prompt and not showing the entered letters as for `passwd` command?

Comment: What is the threat you're trying to counter?  Shoulder surfing or the history entry?

Comment: A installed utility such as [script](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) wouldn't allow to get the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `modify` and set `wifi-sec.psk`, use `nmcli edit id myid` and then `activate` in the interactive mode and it will prompt for password securely.

[image]