# Modifying existing SSID using nmcli

Tags: wifi, nmcli, wifi-hotspot, access-point

Hi so i know i can set up a wifi network using nmcli in this way.

```
nmcli con add type wifi ifname uap0 mode ap con-name <WIFI_AP_NAME> ssid <WIFI_SSID>
nmcli con modify <WIFI_AP_NAME> 802-11-wireless-security.psk <WIFI_PASSWORD>
```

But if i now want to modify the password and ssid of the created wifi network how do i do that? i do not find the correct command in the documentation..
Can i just do this

```
sudo nmcli con down <WIFI_AP_NAME>
sudo nmcli con modify <WIFI_AP_NAME>  802-11-wireless-security.psk "$WIFI_PASSWORD"
sudo nmcli con modify <WIFI_AP_NAME>  ssid <WIFI_SSID>
sudo nmcli con up <WIFI_AP_NAME>
```

Comment: Does this help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316482/how-to-set-wireless-key-with-nmcli-interactively-and-securely-without-entering-i

Comment: @KillianFortman thank you, for the password it does, but for the SSID, is this the standard procedure?

Comment: It seems like this would work using `nmcli con mod <WIFI_AP_NAME> ssid <WIFI_SSID>` if this works I will create an answer for any other people reading this question for an answer. As for standard process I am unsure, but I see no issues with putting the SSID in like this, only issues if you did the password without using the interactive since passwords in cleartext on command line dont mix well with security.